# Finding center of mass for tetrahedron

Tags: mathematical-physics, centroid

I am given a tetrahedron with the following points:

$$\begin{align}
P_1 &= (2,0,1)\\
P_2 &= (-1,1,1)\\
P_3 &= (1,0,2)\\
P_4 &= (3,1,4)
\end{align}$$

and I am tasked with finding its center of mass, M.

My attempt: 
$$\vec{OM} = \frac{1}{3}(\vec{OP_1} + \vec{OP_2} + \vec{OP_3})$$

$\vec{OM_1}$ is the coordinate for the center of mass of the base and $\vec{OM_2}$ is the coordinate of the center of mass of the tetrahedron. To find the center of mass of the tetrahedron, I do the following:

$$\begin{align}
\vec{OM_2} &= \frac{\vec{OM} - \vec{OP_4}}{2} \\
\vec{OM_2} &= \frac{\frac{1}{3}(2,1,4) - (3,1,4)}{2} \\
\vec{OM_2} &= (-\frac{1}{3}, -\frac{1}{6}, -\frac{8}{6})
\end{align}$$

This is wrong since the answer is: $$(\frac{5}{4}, \frac{1}{2}, 2)$$

What have I done wrong? I'd really appreciate tips / explanations exactly where I am wrong.

Comment: Note that there is more "stuff" near $M$ than near $P_4$. The center of mass is going to be closer to $M$ than to $P_4$. I suggest just computing $\vec{OM} = \frac{1}{4}(\vec{OP_1} + \vec{OP_2} + \vec{OP_3} + \vec{OP_4})$.

Comment: You want $\frac14(\vec{OP_1}+\vec{OP_2}+\vec{OP_3}+\vec{OP_4})$

Comment: @Michael Oh alright thanks. Am I supposed to derive this formula myself?Cause I have never seen it. And why is my method not correct?

Comment: You have $\frac16\vec{OP_1}+\frac16\vec{OP_2}+\frac16\vec{OP_3}-\frac12\vec{OP_4}$.  This makes $P_4$ different from the other points, but they all play a similar role.  Also, for an average, the coefficients should add to 1; your coefficients add to $\frac16+\frac16+\frac16-\frac12=0$

Comment: You are working in three dimensions not two. It just happens that the centroid (centre of mass) of a simplex made of uniform material is the same as the centroid of a figure with equal masses at the vertices of the simplex. A simplex in three dimensions is a tetrahedron, which has four vertices. NB In your question you have a tetrahedron, but you say nothing about how the mass is distributed. Is it made of uniform material?

Comment: I have a suggestion for you. First try to find the centroid of a triangle with vertices $P_1$, $P_2$, and $P_3$ which will be $C=\frac 13 (P_1+P_2+P_3)$. Then generalize your method to obtain the centroid of the tetrahedron. It is suggestive that you obtain something like $C=\frac 14 (P_1+P_2+P_3+P_4)$

Answer (score 3):

**Fact.** Let $\{v_1,v_2,v_3,v_4\}$
be the vertices of a tetrahedron $T$. Then the center of mass of $T$ is
$$
\overline x=\frac{1}{4}\bigl(v_1+v_2+v_3+v_4\bigr)
$$
Details of this proof can be found [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/883780/to-find-the-center-of-gravity-of-a-homogeneous-tetrahedron).

Applying the result to your tetrahedron gives
\begin{align*}
\overline x
&= \frac{1}{4}\bigl(v_1+v_2+v_3+v_4\bigr) \\
&= \frac{1}{4}\bigl(2-1+1+3,0+1+0+1,1+1+2+4\bigr) \\
&= \frac{1}{4}(5,2,8)
\end{align*}
which matches your desired result.

Essentially, you need to weight each vertex evenly and you seem to have taken a weighted sum.

Answer (score 0):

suppose first we locate the origin of coordinates at the centroid. assume the position of the centroid is a linear function of the vertices. by symmetry such a function must be

$$
\tau(x_1+x_2+x_3+x_4)
$$

if we uniformly expand the tetrahedron  by a factor $\lambda$ by linearity the coordinates of the centroid are also multiplied by $\lambda$. however the centroid remains at the origin. hence in this system of coordinates we must have
$$
\sum_1^4 x_k=0 \tag{1}
$$
now shift the origin by $a$. in the new system of coordinates the centroid is $-a$, and the vertices are $x_k-a$

hence
$$
\tau\sum_1^4 (x_k-a) =-a \tag{2}
$$
(1) and (2) imply $\tau=\frac14$